# Disable inputs during ajax call without fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have lots of inputs that call Ajax when clicked.  Each as a JavaScript function assigned.  These inputs need to be disabled when Ajax is executing.  This is what I have so far:

```
  $("html").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    $("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     $(this).addClass('busy');
  }).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
     $(this).removeClass('busy');
     $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
  });
```

The only problem is that the inputs turn grey.  How can I avoid this without too much hassle?

I also tried the readonly attribute, but it does not work, for some reason.  This still grays out the buttons, in Chrome at least, and still allows you to click radios and checkboxes.

```
  $("html").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    $("input").attr("readonly", true);
     $(this).addClass('busy');
  }).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
     $(this).removeClass('busy');
     $("input").removeAttr("readonly");
  });
```

**Edit:** It looks like this might be impossible with CSS alone, so I might need to use JavaScript.  This technique works with checkboxes.  Radio buttons might need more work though:

http://jsfiddle.net/q3c2Y/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `disabled` you can use `readonly` attribute maybe.

Comment: Readonly also greys out the checkboxes and also allows interaction. According to this info: "READONLY merely prevents the user from changing the value of the field, not from interacting with the field." http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try the "readonly" attribute.

Comment: I tried readonly and it didn't work for some reason.  I added the code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `disabled` property value to `true`

```
$("input").attr("disabled", true);
```